# Run two blocks in Haskell file using runghc

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have created a function (doLogMap) which executes another function (logMap) and prints the results. However, trying to get doLogMap to call doLogMap recursively results in the below error.

`runghc ./logMap.hs`:

```
logMap.hs:14:30: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `(Double -> [Double] -> IO ())
                                    -> Double -> [Double] -> IO ()'
                  with actual type `IO ()'
    * The function `print' is applied to four arguments,
      but its type `[Double] -> IO ()' has only one
      In the expression: print newpops doLogMap rate newpops
      In the expression:
        let newpops = pops ++ (logMap rate prev : [])
        in print newpops doLogMap rate newpops
   |
14 |                              print newpops
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

I have deduced that there is not a problem with the recursion itself (e.g. calling without printing works). Additionally the line `in print newpops doLogMap rate newpops` in the error message suggests that the print and doLogMap statements have been combined. The question is how do I avoid this?

Code: (logMap.hs)

```
logMap          :: Double -> Double -> Double
logMap 0 0      = 0
logMap rate 0   = 0
logMap 0 pop    = 0
logMap rate pop = rate * pop * (1 - pop)

doLogMap             :: Double -> [Double] -> IO()
doLogMap rate pops = let prev = last pops in
                         let newpops = pops ++ (logMap rate prev : []) in
                             print newpops 
                             doLogMap rate newpops

main :: IO()
main = do
    let r = 2.6
        x = 0.4 in
        let ys = (logMap r x) : [] in
            doLogMap r ys
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform one IO action after another, use a `do` block (or some monadic operator like `>>` and `>>=`). For instance

```
doLogMap :: Double -> [Double] -> IO ()
doLogMap rate pops = do
   let prev    = last pops
       newpops = pops ++ [logMap rate prev]
   print newpops
   doLogMap rate newpops
```

Note that this will loop forever. It is also not terribly efficient, but if your `pops` list is short it won't mutter much.